# Navigation list on the right site

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this navigation

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">Page 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>      
</nav>
```

How can I bring the list items `ul` on the right site?

I do not want to change the direction. I want to move the complete ul item on the right site

Comment: Please clarify - these `li` ARE on the left. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dyooBgr

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when run the html code all thing is fine but you can try different ways
for examples:

```
<nav class="navbar mr-auto navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>

<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">Page 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

- or set `direction` for ul like this `<ul class="navbar-nav" style="direction: ltr">`
- or set style in css for `ul` tag :

  ```
  ul {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: center;
  }
  ```

Comment: This brings not the result I want

Comment: default direction is left but may you have a style that change it, so for caution use `dir: ltr` for `ul` tag

Comment: can you please give me a example

Comment: I do not want to change the direction. I want to bring the complet ul element on the left side